# Ajax not working in Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, ajax, admin-controller

I'm using ajax in Magento 2 admin. But it not working.

My controller:

```
class CustomAjax extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{

protected $resultJsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory

)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

    return $resultJson->setData([
        'messages' => 'Successfully. Params: ',
        'error' => false
    ]);
}
public function indexAction(){
    return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['a' => 'b']);
}}
```

- If I use url of jQuery ajax without `isAjax=true` it say 302 found error in response.
- If I use `isAjax=true` for url ajax it say `invalid form key...`.
- When I add `form_key`: `"form key value"` in `data:{}` of ajax it say `404 Forbidden.`

Please help me, thank so much!

--- update

My url in this case is
http://localhost/magento/admin/mymodule/customAjax/index/key/417a3857c3ee5d1ec2c2c474ce5ce0a217779619d313b12e0d668b950ac80d9d/?isAjax=true

and this is ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data:{
        form_key: formKey
    },
    beforeSend : function(data){

    },
    success : function(data){

    }
});
```

formKey in this case is u5XSzd7EmRKQM7kN

But it say 404 Forbidden error.

Comment: clear cache logout and try

Answer (score 0):

Seem that your Ajax is missing the form key param. We need to add the form key value to url. For example:

```
var form = jQuery('#edit_form');
var action = form.attr('action');

//Assume your form action form.attr('action'): http://{admin_url}/custom/ajax/key/f7f0ad18f378d5458e936d216981f1418702a8381da453a094b6273410f2eb0e/

var newActionUrl = action + '?' + encodeURIComponent(form.find('[name="form_key"]').val());
```

You can see an example: `vendor/magento/module-import-export/view/adminhtml/templates/import/form/before.phtml`

Comment: Hi,

See my updated.

Comment: Thank you but it still same problem, 404 Forbidden.

Comment: Can you post your full url?

Comment: http://localhost/magento/admin/mymodule/customAjax/index/key/2816bd318e1724f3a9240f790a27a88b4a0aade0865a21cac50198e7006393f8/?form_key=3ewNHroJdtKMLp7p

And I also tried this:
http://localhost/magento/admin/mymodule/customAjax/index/key/2816bd318e1724f3a9240f790a27a88b4a0aade0865a21cac50198e7006393f8/?isAjax=true&form_key=3ewNHroJdtKMLp7p

Comment: First of all, I think you should check the custom admin url work or not. For example, try to var_dump or die. **Make sure the custom admin url works**. In this case, don't need to use form key. Second, try with the ajax and form key.

Comment: As i said in my post, if I dont use form key it say "invalid form key" in response.

Look this sreenshot: https://gyazo.com/5244f24cca5b3d7f9e9ee1ac67cafe3f

Comment: Ah! my mistake, I will check again.

Comment: I referenced this your post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151888/how-to-call-controller-using-ajax-in-admin-backend-magento-2